# How Can I do IF ELSE inside Loop FOR?

Tags: loops, robotframework

I have a situation where I need to check if each line ${linhaStatus} has a different value camparing to variable ${statusBuscaPedidos}. If has a diferent value then should click on ${botoes.btnProximo} (click and goes to next page). Ok, he did it once. Next page he should click again, but dont did it.

```
 ${row1}      Get Length    ${E.tableResultBusca}     
 ${rows1}  Set Variable   ${row1}-9
FOR     ${i}    IN RANGE    1     ${rows1}
        ${lineStatus}   Get Text    xpath://*[@id="tblOrderList"]/tbody/tr[${i}]/td[6]
        Log To Console  Status:${lineStatus}
    IF  '${lineStatus}' != '${statusBuscaPedidos}'
             Click Element      ${b.btnProximo}
    ELSE 
     Click Element   ${b.btnAbrir}
    END     
 END
```

Comment: Is ${linhaStatus} a typo for ${lineStatus}? Also what is your error?

Comment: Sorry, I did edit

Comment: @Maria could you remove END under IF Else statement ?

Comment: The code is fine, you can check in the logs how many times the FOR cycle runs and what is doing in each run.